# Casting Simple.Data.Query to POCO Object

Tags: c#, simple.data

I have the following query to read record from database using Join statement in Simple.Data.SqlServer.

```
var productLineItem = (ProductLineItem) (database.Products.All()
                            .Select(
                                database.Products.Name,
                                database.Products.Price
                            )
                        .Join(database.BarCodes)
                        .On(database.BarCodes.ProductID == database.Products.ID)
                        .Where(database.BarCodes.BarCode == barCode).FirstOrDefault())
```

Notice how I have to use FirstOrDefault method as well as wrap the entire statement into parenthesis and then cast it to an object. I do not like this way. I think Simple.Data should be able to work like the following code

```
ProductLineItemproductLineItem = database.Products.Get()
                            .Select(
                                database.Products.Name,
                                database.Products.Price
                            )
                        .Join(database.BarCodes)
                        .On(database.BarCodes.ProductID == database.Products.ID)
                        .Where(database.BarCodes.BarCode == barCode);
```

In the above example I am using Get because I know I will be getting only one record and not a list of records but this query does not work.

How can I achieve what I want using Simple.Data eager loading query and without using those ugly methods?

Comment: If you managed to find an answer please share. I have ended up in the same boat. You can remove the '(' around database in your first example. I am using Dapper more these days because Simple.Data is no longer supported and although not as elegant it's easier is some respects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if what you ideally want is possible, but there is a [`Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Linq method you can use to at least continue the query in a functional style and remove the parenthesis you're not keen on:

```
var productLineItem = database.Products
    .All()
    .Select(database.Products.Name, database.Products.Price)
    .Join(database.BarCodes)
    .On(database.BarCodes.ProductID == database.Products.ID)
    .Where(database.BarCodes.BarCode == barCode)
    .Cast<ProductLineItem>()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I doubt the cast will work as the code is `select`ing an anonymous type.

Comment: It gives me an error object' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'

Comment: The first code example in your question gives that error, or the code in my answer, or both?

Comment: My first code example works fine, Ideally I want the code to be something like my second code example without wrapping the entire query in parenthesis and without using FirstOrDefaut. 

Error occurs in your proposed solution.

Comment: Well like I say, I'm not sure if what you ideally want is possible. I'm working on the assumption that `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` are both the standard Linq extension methods - if it's falling over saying `FirstOrDefault` doesn't exist then I guess that's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting the Q right... But ...
Get returns a element of a sequence, so you can't `Select` there...
On the Other hand :

```
var database = Database.OpenNamedConnection("MyDbCnxString");
var x= 11;                  
var y= 1;
var result= database.Table1.FindAllByX(x)
                        .Select(
                            database.Table1.X,
                            database.Table1.Y
                        )
                    .Join(database.Table2)
                    .On(database.Table2.X== database.Table1.X)
                    .Where(database.Table2.Y== y);

(result as object).Dump("Voila!");
```

This LinqPad code seems to be working Ok.

Not sure what you mean with ugly methods, it looks pretty to me  `:)`

Regarding the cast (if that's  what you don't like about your first query),

```
IEnumerable<IResult> results = (result as SimpleQuery).ActLike<IEnumerable<IResult>>();
//DuckTypeTest
foreach(var r in results)
    Console.WriteLine("IResult {0}:{1}",r.ClientId,r.ClientSeqNo);
```

Is more verbose but at least away from the query

where `IResult`

```
public interface IResult  {
   object X {get;set;}
   object Y {get;set;}
}
```

And where `ActLike<IResult>`

```
using ImpromptuInterface;
```

from [GitHub:ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to manually create and maintain your POCO ProcuctLineItem, and you know that something, somewhere is going to have to generate some SQL, that may or may not be optimal. Would you not be happier and more relaxed using real SQL, then letting [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb) generate the ADO stuff?